# initialization Standard for char[](c-string)

Tags: c++, standards, c-strings

consider the following piece of code:

```
int main(){
    char hi[5] = "Hi!";
    printf("%d", hi[4]);    
}
```

What will be printed? More importantly, **Is there a mention in the standard about what will be printed**, in the *newest* **C++** standards? If there is a mention, where is it?

For some reason recent information about this is tremendously hard to find, and various sources have conflicting information. I've tried en.cppreference.com and cplusplus.com, the former did not have any info, the latter claimed the values are undetermined. However,

```
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char mySt[1000000] = "Hi!";
    for(int i=0;i<1000000;++i){
        if(mySt[i]!='\0') cout << i <<endl;
    }
}
```

This prints only 0, 1, and 2 on my system, and so I expect the "rest" to be initialized to '\0'. Also to my knowledge `char mySt[100000]=""` initializes the whole array `'\0'`, and it just feels awkward to say that it's different with any other string literal. However my instructor claims otherwise(he claims it is "undefined"), I need to back up my claim with recent and concrete evidence, if there is any.

I compiled on MinGW g++ 8.2.0. Thank you in advance.

To clarify,

Comment: `printf("%d", char[4])` in the first example is invalid syntax.

Comment: According to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization) it says "All array elements that are not initialized explicitly are initialized implicitly the same way as objects that have static storage duration.", which means they should be defined to  be zero. Edit: I was looking at C for some reason but the same should apply for C++.

Comment: @JayeonYi — that unhelpful comment was about `char[4]`.

Comment: `printf("%c", '\0')` does print something, a null character. It's a non-printable control character, so you won't be able to see anything on your screen, but if the program's output is redirected to a file there will be a zero byte in the file.

Comment: @aschepler My mistake. Edited. sorry.

Comment: Cppreference documents this at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Character_arrays

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In both C++17 and [the current C++20 draft](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.string), section [dcl.init.string] discusses initializing a character array with a string literal.  Paragraph 3 of that section reads:

> If there are fewer initializers than there are array elements, each element not explicitly initialized shall be zero-initialized.

So yes, all array elements beyond the ones initialized by characters in the literal are guaranteed to be zero values.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char mystr[5] = "Hi!";
    for ( int i = 0; i < sizeof (mystr); i++)
        printf("%d\n", mystr[i]);   
}
```

====== output ======

```
./a.out 
72
105
33
0
0
```